# Fetching List of files from Folder on Amazon S3 in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

i am trying to fetch list of files from the bucket on S3. So is there any way that i can fetch the list of files in the bucket without using AWS IOS SDK? I am working in objective C.

Comment: Here is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454387/how-to-list-the-folders-at-a-specific-path-from-an-amazon-s3-bucket-in-objectiv) to you question. Hope it helps :)